# CSOM SP 2013 - Retrieving a document by ID using folders (not lists)

Tags: development, document-library, csom, document

I'm trying to retrieve a document by its "_dlc_DocId" and I tried the suggestion at [CSOM get document by ID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169131/csom-get-document-by-id) but I end up with nothing (my "items" object is empty and I am sure my _dlc_DocId is correct).

In my case I have a root folder, and document sets (folders) within that folder. The files I'm looking for are within the document sets (sub-folders). Is there a way to retrieve a document by Id using a url (library path + ID)? Just looking for a more direct way other than brute force (iterating over each sub-folder, loading the files for each folder, and then iterating over the files for an ID match).

Comment: YOu can use CAML query to get document by id.

Comment: Right, I tried that as stated in my first sentence but it doesn't seem to be able to find my document, and I'm wondering if it's because it fails to look in sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using below caml query,

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='_dlc_DocId' /><Value Type='Text'>Your_dlc_DocId</Value></Eq><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value></BeginsWith></And></Where></Query></View>"
```

Folder Content Type ID starts with **0x0120**.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the solution I tried previously but the result of my "getItems(query)" is empty after running this query. Do you have the file in sub-folders on your site?

Comment: I have updated my answer..check it.

Answer (score 0):

The CAML query needs to be recursive to query items in folders:

```
<View Scope='Recursive'>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='_dlc_DocId' />
                <Value Type='Text'>UNIQUEID</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```